# column with multiple same entries(name),2 Columns with diff data need to spread into long format

Tags: r, dplyr, reshape

I have data something like below:

```
name       date   balls.purchased   balls.left
   a     feb-17                10            5
   a     Mar-17                12            4
   a    June-18                14            6
   b     Feb-17                16            1
   b    June-18                18            7
```

I have to spread data monthly basis eg below

```
name  Feb-17   Mar-17  June-18
   a      10       12       14
   b      16       0        18
```

Problem what I am facing is, I also want to adjust `balls.left` in the similar fashion, tried with group_by, but didn't see the expected result, need to run regression and this an important parameter.

Any idea to do the same will be highly appreciated.

Comment: How will `balls.purchased` and `balls.left` be separated in the table? In different rows or different columns?

Comment: I want data to be separated by name and spread month-year wise as shown above,but how to adjust other column like balls.left, that its shown in front of the name, I am not getting any idea.

Comment: I can use spread function but how to fit balls.left in this equation is what I am looking forward to

Comment: I'm not quite sure if it's possible with `spread()`, but it definitely is with `dcast()` (see answer below).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without a clear reproducible example I can't be sure, but I believe this does what you want:

```
dd <- tibble::tribble(
  ~name,       ~date,   ~balls.purchased,   ~balls.left,
  'a',     'Feb-17',                10,            5,
  'a',     'Mar-17',                12,            4,
  'a',    'June-18',                14,            6,
  'b',     'Feb-17',                16,            1,
  'b',    'June-18',                18,            7
)

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dd %>%
  gather(key, value, -name, -date) %>%
  unite('key', date, key) %>%
  spread(key, value, fill = 0)

# A tibble: 2 x 7
  name  `Feb-17_balls.left` `Feb-17_balls.purchased` `June-18_balls.left` `June-18_balls.purchased` `Mar-17_balls.left` `Mar-17_balls.purchased`
  <chr>               <dbl>                    <dbl>                <dbl>                     <dbl>               <dbl>                    <dbl>
1 a                       5                       10                    6                        14                   4                       12
2 b                       1                       16                    7                        18                   0                        0
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possible solution with `reshape2`. First melt the table so that the quantity of balls is one variable only, and a new column describes which of the two types.

Let's call your data `df`

```
library(reshape2)
df1 <- melt(df)
```

Then cast the data to put the months into separate columns.

```
dcast(df1, name + variable ~ date)

#  name        variable feb-17 Feb-17 June-18 Mar-17
#1    a balls.purchased     10     NA      14     12
#2    a      balls.left      5     NA       6      4
#3    b balls.purchased     NA     16      18     NA
#4    b      balls.left     NA      1       7     NA
```

In the formula we are telling the function that `name` and `variable` are ID variables and entries for `date` are going to be value variables.

Comment: I agree to the above approach , but again the names are repeating themselves and I am looking forward to how something can be done, that name doesn't repeats itself in another row

Comment: I think you need to edit your question with the desired output given more clearly.... otherwise it's difficult to help.

Answer (score 1):

This is my suggested tidyverse solution:

```
library(tidyverse)

df<-read.table(text="name       date   balls.purchased   balls.left
   a     Feb-17                10            5
               a     Mar-17                12            4
               a    June-18                14            6
               b     Feb-17                16            1
               b    June-18                18            7",header=T)
df %>% 
  gather("id","value",3:4) %>% 
 spread(date,value)
```

This yields:

```
name              id Feb-17 June-18 Mar-17
1    a      balls.left      5       6      4
2    a balls.purchased     10      14     12
3    b      balls.left      1       7     NA
4    b balls.purchased     16      18     NA
```

It appears that you want only two rows. That seems unlikely in my opinion given the names are not unique unless you go back to a wide format.